# Running slow web drivers like Watir in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I created an application that uses Watir to automate logging in and perform a couple of functions within a site.

Right now it's written 100% purely in ruby classes that I was just executing in irb, but I want to put it into a Rails application and put it online. I haven't been able to find much information about using something like Capybara or Watir for anything other than testing. Is this because of how slow they are or is it a capabilities issue?

Would I be able to run a background process that opens a browser with Watir and performs a few functions for each user in production?

Another question I have is how to keep the session over a longer period of time. There are two sites that require 2FA that my app logs into. If I wanted to log in and perform a function once an hour with a Watir browser, I could create it as a background process (if that works). But when the process is done the browser closes and when the background process runs again in an hour it requires 2FA again.

My other worry is speed. If I have 50 users that all need to run a Watir browser at the same time I imagine that will be slow. I am not worried as much about speed as long as they run and collect the data and perform the few actions we need, but how it will effect the applications integrity.

Comment: using a API is faster and more dependable than an automated browser. The speed issue aside, what happens if the site you're scraping suddenly changes their markup? So I would say don't put an automated browser as a core part of your user-facing app unless you absolutely must.

Comment: One of the two sites API is out of the question. I'll probably change the scraper to an API, but my main feature of my app needs the automated browser unfortunately.

Comment: anywhere you need a browser, you can use an HTTP library

Answer (score 2):

WATIR is specifically designed as a testing tool..  WATIR stands for Web Application Testing In Ruby.  It's design is centered around interacting with a browser the way a user would, effectively simulating the same actions a user would take when using a site.  That it would be sub-optimal for other tasks is to be expected.  Due to scraping and testing having very similar activities, there a a number of people that use watir for that task, but it is not designed for that purpose, and it is unlikely that the WATIR developers would ever add features specific to data scraping verses testing.

With the things you are contemplating, you should ask yourself if you are doing the equivalent of using a socket wrench as a hammer, and if there might be a better tool you could use.

If the sites you are interacting with support an API, then that would be the preferred way to interact with them, to get information from the site.   If that is not supported, you may want to consider looking at other gems that would let you request the site HTML or parse the HTML directly (e.g. Nokogiri)

You should also inspect the terms of service for the sites you are interacting with (if you don't own them) to ensure that there are not prohibitions against using 'robots' or other automated means to access the site.  If so, then using Watir in the way you propose may end up getting you banned from access to the site if the pattern of your access is obviously the result of an automated process.

Comment: Nokogiri was my first goto. The sites I am using it for are very Javascript heavy and the only scrapers I have ever used are Nokogiri and Mechanize which both were ruled out. I created my original with Watir because it was such a simple solution to something I thought I would only use once. Now that the idea of putting it into production I realize this is no where near the optimal solution. I've already taken apart half the application to use API's where I can, but for two of them it has to be automated. Is there an alternative to Nokogiri that reads JS?

Comment: I think it would need to both read and execute JS, and I don't know of such a beast.   Executing JS code is mostly limited to browsers and things like NODE.   Even then I'm pretty sure Node does not execute JS the way a browser does, not exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually done more often than people think. Maybe not specifically with Watir, but running a browser automation task in a job. The jobs should be queued and run asynchronously, preferably in a different process than your main web app.

I wrote about this strategy here: https://blogstephenarifin.wordpress.com/2018/08/23/integrating-a-third-party-without-an-api-using-rails-5-and-heroku/

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself having to use Watir then the best way is to use it to render the page (for example in headless mode for javascript), save it and then use Nokogiri to process it.  Apis are suggested a lot by people who don't and can't find a use for scraping but at times is necessary and perfectly legit (you may even be scraping your own data). Apis are not  a universal option.

Second you should probably regulate its use to a background job.  If you have end users (and you really shouldn't have many simultaneous users)  many services inform customers data will be available in a few hours to a few days